# Font increase and decrease on click

Tags: html, css

I have a '+' and '-' button in my page. On clicking '+' I need to increase font size by 10px, again onclick will increase size by 12. Same way for '-' it decrements. How can I write css class for that?

```
<ul id="box">
    <li><a title="t1" id="SizePlus" href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a title="t2" id="SizeMinus" href="#"></a></li>
</ul> 

#box
{
list-style-type: none;
display: block;
clear: both;
}

#box li a 
{
display: block;
float: left;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
text-indent: -10000px;
}
```

Comment: you plan to do this with just html+css?

Comment: Yes.. without any javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not** possible with css only. you will have to use javascript to achieve  this...

useful site http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/text-resizing-with-jquery/

Comment: Then can you give me some tips or links?

Comment: Just one div part is in(de)creasing.Not all. Why is that?I need all the contents inside the body to resize?

Comment: I am getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null 
resizeText
onclick     var c = document.getElementById("page"); function resizeText(multiplier) { if (c.style.fontSize == "") { c.style.fontSize = "1.0em"; } c.style.fontSize = parseFloat(c.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em"; }

Answer (score 1):

I think only using  css it is not possible to do.Use  javascript try this llink

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-change-font-size-onclick-in-wordpress-with-javascript/